# Find if area contains a specific Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a mod for the game Unturned, which runs on the Unity Engine.
The mod is nearly ready, but I have some problems with my `Area` class.
It represents an rectangle area, which is constructed given two diagonal points.
[image: An Image]

The problematic part is the `Contains(Vector3)` method, which does not work.

```
   public class Area
   {
    public Vector3 A;
    public Vector3 B;

    public Area(Vector3 A, Vector3 B)
    {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
    }

    public bool Contains(Vector3 player)
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(A, B) >= Vector3.Distance(player,  A) 
          && Vector3.Distance(A, B) >= Vector3.Distance(player, B);
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix the `Contains` method? Am I missing something?
BTW: Althogh im using Vector3, im talking about 2D Space!

Comment: You problem is geometric. Given 2 points you can define infinite number of rectangles that have these points as opposite edges

Comment: @apomene so I have to define four points?

Comment: Try something like this:

bool GameObjects::Body::isInRectangle(const irr::core::vector2df &objectPositionToCheck, DOUBLE radius)
{
  return this->Position().X >= objectPositionToCheck.X - radius && this->Position().X <= objectPositionToCheck.X + radius &&
    this->Position().Y >= objectPositionToCheck.Y - radius && this->Position().Y <= objectPositionToCheck.Y + radius;
}

Comment: @nickkoro  Yep, Excatly

Comment: And how should I implent Contains(Vector3)? The same way i did but checking all four sites X and Y?

Comment: You can use a two-point representation of a rectangle though if you constrain it to be axis-aligned in a particular coordinate system (eg. World space). Explaining how you plan to be using this class can help narrow down the complexity of the solution: will it only be on the horizontal plane? Can it be a diagonal rectangle, or will all its sides always be parallel to an axis?

Comment: Players will define such an area using in-game commands. The can define both points completly independet.

Comment: Okay. Will the two points always be 2D (ie. One of their position components will always be the same)? If so, will they always have the same Z-axis value? And is the expectation that the rectangle will be axis-aligned, or can it be rotated any which way? (If it can be rotated, then 2 points is not enough because it can represent an infinite number of possibilities.)

Comment: @Serlite Yes, the restangle is in fact 2D. Im using Vector3 because the Users coodinates are Vector3, so I could use Vector2 for the area as well.

Comment: Im quite new to game-deverlopment, what do u mean with "axis-aligned"? That the site X for example does not match coodinate-system X?

Comment: Ah, as in - all the sides of the rectangle are parallel to an axis in the coordinate system you're using. An example of making the rectangle you supplied axis-aligned would be if the side from Point A to the point above Point Y was parallel to the X-axis, and the side from Point Y to the point above it was parallel to the Z-axis. Are your rectangles going to be oriented like that, or can the sides between vertices of the rectangles be diagonal relative to the axes?

Comment: @Serlite Thank you for the explanation. Yes, they can be diagonal too.

Comment: Hmm...that complicates the situation then. In that case, you'll need to define at least three pieces of information for a rectangle - either add a third point, or supply the vector representing the local x- or y-axis of the rectangle. Otherwise, the two points you've supplied [really could represent an infinite number of rectangles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQSZe.png)

Comment: Well, I'll just make a third and forth point and let the question open, mby someone find it useful. Thank you for help.

Comment: Alright. If you run into any problems with that implementation, feel free to update this question with new information (or if the question differs significantly, open a new one).

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best method, but it works!

```
public bool Contains(Vector3 player)
{
    float tax, tay, tbx, tby;
    if(a.x > b.x) { tax = a.x; tbx = b.x; } else { tax = b.x; tbx = a.x; }
    if(a.y > b.y) { tay = a.y; tby = b.y; } else { tay = b.y; tby = a.y; }
    return (player.x < tax && player.x > tbx && player.y < tay && player.y > tby)
}
```